# ArgMax and Color properties: Unable to encode BOTH line end point marks AND highest/lowest circle marks

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

** **FINAL EDIT: Resolved by @DavideBacci - I'm indebted to you** **
[image: Final Image]

**EDIT: 3rd partial success attempt** - closer yet again, but needed to use helper measures to display high and low points - ideally would love to achieve same result without extra DAX measures
[image: 3rd attempt]

**EDIT: 2nd failed attempt** - closer but still having encoding issues
[image: 2nd_Attempt]

**EDIT: 1st failed attempt:**

I have become stuck again with Vega-lite, attempting to layer points for the line end circle marks and text labels, AND also layer the highest/lowest point marks, using filter and color properties:

[image: Line chart using "color": and "argmax": expressions - attempting to get highest/lowest marks AND latest mark points and text labels]

I'm almost there, but I'm missing something fundamental as I am unable to get the marks to encode correctly -

Any help is greatly appreciated. - PBIX available here: [Temperature_DEV_argmax_PAGE2](https://github.com/PBIQueryous/Deneb/blob/main/Dev/Temperature_DEV.pbix)
[image: IdealSolution]

Latest code:
[image: latest code]

```json
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "DayOfYear",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "_temp",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Year",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "Year",
            "oneOf": [
              "2023",
              "2022",
              "2021",
              "1979-2000 mean"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "DayOfYear",
              "type": "temporal"
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"zero": false}
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "Year",
              "type": "nominal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "COLOR_LINES_BLUE_RED",
          "layer": [
            {
              "mark": {"type": "line"},
              "encoding": {
                "x": {
                  "field": "DayOfYear",
                  "type": "temporal"
                },
                "y": {
                  "field": "_temp",
                  "type": "quantitative",
                  "scale": {
                    "zero": false
                  }
                },
                "color": {
                  "field": "Year",
                  "type": "nominal",
                  "scale": {
                    "domain": [
                      "2023",
                      "2022",
                      "2021",
                      "1979-2000 mean"
                    ],
                    "range": [
                      "crimson",
                      "#000FFF50",
                      "#000FFF80",
                      "orange"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {
              "filter": "datum['_temp'] == datum['_highpoints'] || datum['_temp'] == datum['_lowpoints']"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "point",
            "filled": true,
            "stroke": "black",
            "strokeWidth": 0.8,
            "shape": {
              "expr": "datum['_temp'] == datum['_highpoints'] ? 'triangle-down' : 'triangle-up'"
            },
            "size": 250,
            "opacity": 1,
            "yOffset": {
              "expr": "datum['_temp'] == datum['_highpoints'] ? -10 : 10"
            }
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "DayOfYear",
              "type": "temporal"
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"zero": false}
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "Year",
              "type": "nominal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {
              "filter": "datum['_temp'] == datum['_highpoints'] || datum['_temp'] == datum['_lowpoints']"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "filled": true,
            "stroke": "whitesmoke",
            "strokeWidth": 8,
            "size": 15,
            "fontWeight": "1000",
            "opacity": 1,
            "yOffset": {
              "expr": "datum['_temp'] == datum['_highpoints'] ? -30 : 30"
            }
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "DayOfYear",
              "type": "temporal"
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"zero": false}
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "Year",
              "type": "nominal"
            },
            "text": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "format": ",.3~s"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {
              "filter": "datum['_temp'] == datum['_highpoints'] || datum['_temp'] == datum['_lowpoints']"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "filled": true,
            "size": 15,
            "fontWeight": "1000",
            "opacity": 1,
            "yOffset": {
              "expr": "datum['_temp'] == datum['_highpoints'] ? -30 : 30"
            }
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "format": ",.3~s"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not following the problem on this one. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Similar to the previous problem, the intention is a 'purist' approach where vega-lite handles everything inline. I wanted to have two main layers: 1) a line showing years 2023,2022,2021 - to display the highest, lowest, last points; and 2) the second layer showing all lines for all years (1979-2023) in greyscale.  I wasn't able to do this entirely entirely in Vega-Lite, I had to add additional helper measures to identify the high/low marks. Having achieved this, I'm not not able to add the second layer of lines, I can't get out of the layer filtered for 2021-2023,

latest PBIX in Github

Comment: I *think* what I'm trying to accomplish is along the lines of - the window expression allows us to identify the high/low points for a single line, but I'd like the high/low points to show against the years 2021-2023, can the window expression iterate against each of the line individually? Would groupby resolve this? I'm trying to follow the documentation, but I'm baffling myself. - POST EDIT: actually - I think "window" and "groupby" resolves this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "DayOfYear",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "_temp",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "Year",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "Year",
            "oneOf": [
              "2023",
              "2022",
              "2021",
              "1979-2000 mean"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "joinaggregate": [
            {
              "op": "max",
              "field": "_temp",
              "as": "highest"
            }
          ],
          "groupby": ["Year"]
        },
          {
          "joinaggregate": [
            {
              "op": "min",
              "field": "_temp",
              "as": "lowest"
            }
          ],
          "groupby": ["Year"]
        }
      ],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "line"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "DayOfYear",
              "type": "temporal"
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"zero": false}
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "Year",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "2023",
                  "2022",
                  "2021",
                  "1979-2000 mean"
                ],
                "range": [
                  "crimson",
                  "#000FFF50",
                  "#000FFF80",
                  "orange"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {
              "filter": "datum['_temp'] == datum['highest'] || datum['_temp'] == datum['lowest']"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "point",
            "filled": true,
            "stroke": "black",
            "strokeWidth": 0.8,
            "shape": {
              "expr": "datum['_temp'] == datum['highest'] ? 'triangle-down' : 'triangle-up'"
            },
            "size": 250,
            "opacity": 1,
            "yOffset": {
              "expr": "datum['_temp'] == datum['highest'] ? -10 : 10"
            }
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "DayOfYear",
              "type": "temporal"
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"zero": false}
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "Year",
              "type": "nominal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {
              "filter": "datum['_temp'] == datum['highest'] || datum['_temp'] == datum['lowest']"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "filled": true,
            "stroke": "whitesmoke",
            "strokeWidth": 8,
            "size": 15,
            "fontWeight": "1000",
            "opacity": 1,
            "yOffset": {
              "expr": "datum['_temp'] == datum['highest'] ? -30 : 30"
            }
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "DayOfYear",
              "type": "temporal"
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"zero": false}
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "Year",
              "type": "nominal"
            },
            "text": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "format": ",.3~s"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "transform": [
            {
              "filter": "datum['_temp'] == datum['highest'] || datum['_temp'] == datum['lowest']"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "filled": true,
            "size": 15,
            "fontWeight": "1000",
            "opacity": 1,
            "yOffset": {
              "expr": "datum['_temp'] == datum['highest'] ? -30 : 30"
            }
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
              "field": "_temp",
              "format": ",.3~s"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's beautiful @DavideBacci - that's absolutely perfect, and how clean is that "joinaggregate" expression!? This is precisely what I had in mind thank you. Thank you for perservering through my waffle, I haven't been expressing myself very well.

Comment: No problem and happy to help ;)